# Script conflicts with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am looking to add charts to sortable portlets in JQuery. I just ran into an issue and was wondering what causes it and how I can fix it or get around it. My original sources were:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then I added:

```
<script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
```

When I added these, the frames and ui functions of each portlet no longer work or are visible, but the text still is. What conflicts are causing this and what is the proper way to add something like a chart to an individual portlet?

Comment: You're referencing two entirely different versions of jQuery at the same time.  If you're not separating between the two in your code, then there's your problem.  In *most* cases, you should be using only one version of jQuery.

Comment: @David Thank you! You were exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including jQuery twice:

```
<!-- here --><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- and here --><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove the second line (earlier version) and you should be in business.